# How to Set a array data First value in Tableview First Section and remaining array data value in Second Section of tableview in iOS?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

i am newbie in iOS and i know this Question is asked for many times but i am not getting solution.i made an application with tableview here is my tableview code Containing two section and i want to Fill this section with JSON Data.i made  Two CustomCell. it Display well but i am not able to fill my JSON Parsing Data.

my code is.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.section == 0)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierOne=@"CellOne";
    CustumCell *cellOne =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierOne];
    if (cellOne == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibOne=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellOne=[nibOne objectAtIndex:0];
        cellOne.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
    {
        [cellOne.spinner startAnimating];
        NSDictionary *dict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSString *img2=[dict valueForKey:@"front_image"];
        [cellOne.storeImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[img2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Setting.png"] options:SDWebImageHighPriority completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL)
         {
             [cellOne.spinner stopAnimating];
             cellOne.spinner.hidesWhenStopped=YES;

         }];
}
    return cellOne;
}
else
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifierTwo=@"CellTwo";
    TableCell *cellTwo=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierTwo];
    if (cellTwo == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nibTwo=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cellTwo=[nibTwo objectAtIndex:0];
        cellTwo.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    }
    return cellTwo;
}
return nil;
}
```

And Here Tableview section is Two and also code for numberofRow is

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (section == 0)
{
    return 1;
    NSLog(@"Images %@",self.imageArray);
}
else
{
    return self.imageArray.count - 1;
}
}
```

when there is no any Data then it Shows as i want, but i am not able to fill my Data Please provide me any Solution.

Comment: You may no attempt to apply your data to the cells in section 1.

Comment: @rmaddy no attempt to apply means?

Comment: You have no code that updates `cellTwo` with data for the specific row in the section. You don't make use of your `imageArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy first i want only display my First Cell With my First Data Array Value so i not write code for Second Section.and here imageArray is my JSON Parsing array. You Understand what i say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AshishGabani

look at the below code, what i understand for your requirement

I have taken an array, contains values like this

NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];

**Next TableView Methods:**

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) return 1;
    return imageArray.count-1;

}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Simple";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.section==0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1];

    }
    return cell;

}
```

Just Comment you existing code and Copy this code and Paste your Xcode ViewController and Run the simulator, I think i reached your requirement .